# How do I scrape a page without knowing the structure?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python.  If it helps, I'm trying to get the spreads from https://tn.sportsbook.fanduel.com/basketball/nba/philadelphia-76ers-@-brooklyn-nets-32284119.  First, I had to add the following header to circumvent the 403 response:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
#That's not my laptop, I just copied the solution from somewhere else on this site.

page_to_scrape = requests.get("https://tn.sportsbook.fanduel.com/basketball/nba/philadelphia-76ers-@-brooklyn-nets-32284119",headers=headers)
```

All I know is that the information I need is in the aria-label of a div tag with the team name and the string `Spread Betting`.
My attempts:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_to_scrape.text, "html.parser")
soup.prettify()
```

got me a string of the html source with no div tags.

I also tried

```
nestedDiv_list = soup.find('div')
x= nestedDiv_list.descendants
for lists in nestedDiv_list.descendants:
    print(lists)
```

But, I think I'm doing that wrong because I just get the outermost div tag with nothing inside.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do much with traditional web scraping tools, since all the content of the site is dynamically loaded via JavaScript. So, you have to analyse how this happens. For this, look at the network tab in your browser's developer tools to see what data gets loaded when and from where. Then you can access these endpoints directly to obtain the data.

If you don't find or recognize your data there, try opening all dropdowns or other interactive elements to make sure your data is loaded or read the scripts that are used to load the data.

Comment: Can you please explain how to tell what data gets loaded from where, and how to access the endpoints?  Or at least, what I should look into to be able to do that?  Thanks.